# Landside transit visa in Dubai for a spouse of a US citizen

Tags: transit-visas, uae, afghan-citizens

I am U.S. citizen. If my spouse gets a U.S. Visa in Kabul, Afghanistan,  would she be able to get a transit visa in Dubai so that she could go out with me for shopping and hanging out?

Comment: What is her country of citizenship?

Comment: By the location of the visa application I am guessing Afganistan.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your spouse as a US visa has no impact on their eligibility for Dubai transit visa.

What will determine eligibility is the citizenship; assuming your spouse has Afghani citizenship - they will need to apply in advance for a visa (even for transit).

If you are flying Emirates, you can arrange a visa through them. For other airlines, [`marhaba`](http://www.marhabaservices.com/) can arrange transit visas.